# Verify javacard signature ALG_ECDSA_SHA on bouncy castle

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle, javacard

My problem looks like this: im generating a signature on javaCard (jcdk 2.2.2) and when when i want to verify it on the terminal using BouncyCastle the signature isnt always verified- 1 in 3,66 (average in 100 tries) signatures are verified, the rest in returning false. when i verify the signature on the card it always returns true, but on the terminal it usually returns false, but sometimes true. because the terminal sometimes gives a positive answer i think that the code is ok and the reason is some where else but i can be wrong.

on javacard im usign Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, and on the terminal Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA", "BC") i tried also SHA1withDetECDSA but i behaves similar.

please help.

Comment: Looks weird! 2.66 of 3.66 is too much for noises on the transmission! Can you add the programs? (generator & verifier)

Comment: Note that the [tag:signature] tag is not correct as that's about *method* signatures.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, please mark one of answers as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that JavaCard and BouncyCastle use different format of the resulting signature. For example for the Prime192v1 curve the resulting JavaCard signature is always 56 bytes long, but the Bouncy Castle signature is sometimes shorter, because it omits leading zeros in EC point coordinates.

The JavaCard signature (for Prime192v1, again) looks like this in the hexadecimal format:

`30 36 02 19 [25 bytes of the first coord] 02 19 [25 bytes of the second coord]`

(it is a DER encoded structure: SEQUENCE of two INTEGERs)

However, BouncyCastle does not expect leading these zeros in EC coords. So you have to remove them and fix the DER structure, for example

```
30 36 02 19 **00 00** [the rest 23 bytes of the first coord] 02 19 **00** [24 bytes of the second coord]
```

from JavaCard must be converted for Bouncy Castle to:

`30 **33** 02 **17** [23 bytes of the first coord] 02 **18** [24 bytes of the second coord]`

The reason why you sometimes verify the signature correctly is simple: sometimes there are no leading zeros in your JavaCard signature coordinates.

**EDIT: inspired by TajnosAgentos' observation:**

BouncyCastle encodes coords as signed integers, JavaCard always as unsigned integers. That is why BouncyCastle adds a special leading zero (although it trims other leading zeros) whenever the most significant bit of the first byte is 1, because the coord is always a positive number.

Comment: this is my key signature (didnt pass verification) 30.__34__.02.__18__.8E.B6.C4.15.9E.A5.9B.4E.45.A1.6B.41.EA.DB.02.BA.75.DF.F7.19.66.DD.BA.D0.02.__18__.BB.BB.DE.3F.82.54.B4.D9.14.D2.28.4D.54.9B.02.5D.13.48.49.57.C0.44.1E.21. it is 54 bytes long - i removed the SW so maybe that is the reason. i tried to replace the marker values .__AA__. with different, but it works only with 34, 18, 18. i dont know what i'mdoing wrong ;(

Comment: my signature looks like this 30 34 02 18 [24 bytes] 02 18 [24 byte] [SW - 90 00] PS. kay can be verified (not always) with makred values 34-18-18 and 36-18-18

Comment: What elliptic urve do you use?

Comment: http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf
2.5.1 Recommended Parameters secp192k1 on top of page 12 (not browser page 12, but page 12 on paper) ;)

Comment: point G in uncompressed form - it does not work in compressed form, at least for that curve

Comment: Could you specify which Java Card implementation you are using? If it includes more than one leading zero or a leading zero and then a byte smaller than 0x80 then the implementation of the Java Card is *not valid*. I'm [pretty sure](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24862/1172) that the signature should be DER encoded, and in that case the shortest possible encoding of a *signed* integer should be used.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes JavaCard 2.2.2. This is the behaviour of all NXP chips I have had in my hands so far (J3A081, J2A128, J3E145 etc.). Are you saying that the ECDSA signature in JavaCard does not have a fixed length?

Comment: X9.62 signatures consist of an ASN.1 SEQUENCE that holds two INTEGER values. Those integer values are signed numbers and *should be encoded using the minimum number of octets available*. If you get a `02` (INTEGER tag), length byte and then `0000` then the *encoding* of the given signature is certainly invalid. Beware that the coordinates should always be positive: the leftmost bit of the INTEGER should never be 1 (so the INTEGER should not start with `8x` to `Fx`, in that case the INTEGER should start with `00 8x` to `00 Fx`).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes "Regardless of the choice of solution, Java Card requires fixed lengths for the signatures, so the signature co-ordinate data must be pre-padded with 0x00 to the correct coordinate length and the signature coordinate and header length must be updated." See http://0x9000.blogspot.cz/2011/01/bouncycastle-ecc-and-javacard.html (although this page is no authority...)

Comment: I think I'm a better authority on this. And I'm pretty sure it is incorrect. It looks like a mixture of r and s converted into octet strings according to BSI 03111 and the SEC1/X9.62 ASN.1 DER encoding.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So you have a 55 bytes long Prime192v1 ecc signature? I do not argue, it is obviously incorrect, but it really happens on my cards...

Comment: This evaluated to a bug in a specific JCOP version.

Comment: The signature is not always 56 bytes long! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. I dont know why this works, byt it does... The signing function on javacard should look like this:

```
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

    signature.init(ecPrivateKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
    short sLen = signature.sign(helloWorld, (short) 0, (short)helloWorld.length, scratch, (short) 0);

    if((short)scratch[4] < 0 || (short)scratch[30] < 0)
    {
        sign(apdu);
    }
    else
    {
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(scratch, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) sLen);

        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)sLen);
    }
```

ist a "prototype" function. it workes so im sharing it first, later maybe i will improve it a little. scratch is a byte array declared somewhere else.

like VOJTA posted earlier the signature (in my example) looks something like this:

30 34 02 18 [24 bytes NO1] 02 18 [24 byte NO2] [SW - 90 00]

the SW is NOT needed. so the SHORT value of the FIRST byte of [24 bytes NO1] and the SHORT value of the first byte of the [24 bytes NO2] cannot be nagative. i dont know why this works. i printed the verified and not verified signatures and i was looking for any differences, and i found this. I made over 1000 tries and verification ALWAYS returned TRUE. the probability that this 2 bytes will be nagative is 1/4 ((-128,127), 0 goes to positive, half negative, half positive -> 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4)  so probably thats why earlier only 1 on 3,66 signatures vere verified. if someone knows why it worsk i will be happy to read his post

EDIT

now i know how it works. there are to solutions of this problem. one is the solution above- generate signatures until the SHORT value of 2 elements of the array are positive and the second solution:

the signature looks something like this:

30 **34** 02 **18** [24 bytes NO1] 02 **18** [24 byte NO2]

now the algorithm about which VOJTA wrote about (the bold values will be changed if needed)
lex x=34 (SECOND BYTE OF THE SIGN- this may vary, in my signature it is 34). 
if first bites of [24 byte NO1] and [24 byte NO2] are positive then do nothing with the signature.
if the SHORT value of the first byte of [24 bytes NO1] is negative then we have to add ONE to X (now x=35), add ONE to the 18 next to the first byte of [24 bytes NO1] and insert a value 00 next to the 18 (now 19) to the signature. if the SHORT value of the first byte of [24 bytes NO2] is negative then we have to add ONE to X (now x=36), add ONE to the 18 next to the first byte of [24 bytes NO2] and insert 00 next to 18 (now 19). if both first bytes vere negative then the signature should look something like this:

30 **36** 02 **19** **00** [24 bytes NO1] 02 **19** **00** [24 byte NO2]

if only first first byte of [24 bytes NO1] was negative, and the first byte of [24 bytes NO2] was positive the the signature should look somethung like this

30 **35** 02 **19** **00** [24 bytes NO1] 02 18 [24 byte NO2]

and the last case:
if only first first byte of [24 bytes NO1] was positive, and the first byte of [24 bytes NO2] was negativethe the signature should look somethung like this

30 **35** 02 18 [24 bytes NO1] 02 **19** **00** [24 byte NO2]

hope that i will be useful

Comment: The integers should be DER encoded. DER uses the shortest possible format of a *signed* integer. To retrieve this encoding in Java, use `new BigInteger(1, [24 byte encoding]).toByteArray()` which interprets the 24 bytes as positive unsigned integer, and then encodes to the minimum signed representation. Otherwise you may still have failures.

Answer (score 0):

@vojta answer is misleading. The trick is that the sign method returns the length of the signature.

Have a look:

```java
// Assuming you have already initialized the privateKey and publicKey objects

// Define the input message to be signed
byte[] message = { /* your message bytes here */ };

// Create a Signature object for ECDSA with SHA-1
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, false);

// Initialize the signature object with the private key for signing
signature.init(privateKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);

// Create a temporary buffer for the signature
byte[] signatureBuffer = new byte[signature.getLength()];

// Sign the message and store the signature in the buffer
short signatureLength = signature.sign(message, (short) 0, (short) message.length, signatureBuffer, (short) 0);

// Initialize the signature object with the public key for verification
signature.init(publicKey, Signature.MODE_VERIFY);

// Verify the signature against the original message
boolean result = signature.verify(message, (short) 0, (short) message.length, signatureBuffer, (short) 0, signatureLength);

// Print the result
System.out.println("Signature verification result: " + result);
```

If you then take only the first `signatureLength` bytes of the `signature` buffer BC can verify it no problem without making modifications.